# Entity Framework modelling one-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many

I don't know how to configure following relations in EF:

Imagine I need to create some language dictionary model. I have an item (word for example) in one language and in another language. There is some relation between these two items.

For instance: "hund" (German) -> "dog" (English), relation type is "Translate"

```
public enum Language
{
    English,
    German,
}

public class Item
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemRelation> ItemRelations { get; set; }
}

public enum ItemRelationType
{
    Translate,
    Synonym,
}

public class ItemRelation
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemID")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelativeItemID")]
    public Item RelativeItem { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ItemRelationType Type { get; set; }
}
```

EF standard migration throw some error in one case or creates columns or FKs I don't wont (`Item_ID` etc.) in the other.

I guess I need to configure some fluent api - but I am not sure how...

Comment: "some language dictionary model", " some relation", "some error", "one case - the other case" -- this is all rather vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the actual FK fields `ItemID` and `RelativeItemID`:

And to configure the navigation property you can use `InverseProperty` attribute, along with disabling a bit of EF convention(shown below).

```
public class ItemRelation
{
   public long ID { get; set; }

   public long ItemID { get; set; } // Missing 
   [ForeignKey("ItemID")]
   [InverseProperty("ItemRelations")]
   public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

   public long RelativeItemID { get; set; } // Missing 
   [ForeignKey("RelativeItemID")]
   [InverseProperty("RelativeItemRelations")]
   public virtual Item RelativeItem { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public ItemRelationType Type { get; set; }
}
```

The declaration above uses `virtual` so that lazy loading works. It's not necessary and you can remove it. The consequence is that lazy loading won't work, which is ok too.

Assuming you want a navigation property for the second relation you need to add the property:

```
public class Item
{
...
   public virtual ICollection<ItemRelation> RelativeItemRelations { get; set; }
...
}
```

And then disable the cascading delete convention by overriding `OnModelCreating`, if you haven't already, in your context class as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
...
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
...
```

*This solution should work but it is effectively disabling cascade delete to all one to many relationships. The upside is that you can get it back on a case by case basis by using fluent api.*

The second way to achieve what you want is to just use fluent api as follows:

Add the second navigation property to your `Item` entity:

```
public class Item
{
...
   public virtual ICollection<ItemRelation> RelativeItemRelations { get; set; }
...
}
```

`ItemRelation` entity is missing the FKs, so here it is:

public class ItemRelation
    {
       public long ID { get; set; }

```
   public long ItemID { get; set; } // Missing 
   public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

   public long RelativeItemID { get; set; } // Missing 
   public virtual Item RelativeItem { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public ItemRelationType Type { get; set; }
}
```

And to configure the navigation property, and avoid the cascading issue, you just define the relationship using fluent api:

```
public TheContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ItemRelation> ItemRelations { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Entity<ItemRelation>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Item)
                .WithMany(t => t.ItemRelations)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ItemID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

      modelBuilder.Entity<ItemRelation>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.RelatedItem)
                .WithMany(t => t.RelativeItemRelations)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.RelativeItemID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);       


      // Uncomment the following if you want to disable all cascading deletes and automatic fk creation conventions
      // modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
      // modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
      // modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    ...
  }
}
```

[Read here for an opinion on why you might consider disabling those conventions.](http://andreyzavadskiy.com/2016/01/12/code-first-model-conventions-something-youd-like-to-turn-off/)

Comment: Yes. But by this way I have following error: "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ItemRelations_dbo.Items_RelativeItemID' on table 'ItemRelations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors." Maybe I just need set cascadeDelete to false - I don't know this properties well.

Comment: @Petr One solution is to disable the cascading delete, and the other one is to use fluent api to configure the relation. I have added both to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to get away with this:

```
public class ItemRelation
{

    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PrimaryItemId")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public long PrimaryItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelatedItemId")]
    public Item RelatedItem { get; set; }
    public long RelatedItemId { get; set; }

    public ItemRelationType RelationType;
}
```

Notice that this class now has TWO relations to the `Item` entity, resulting in two foreign keys. Notice that each `Item` property has a `[ForeignKey]` attribute, with the string argument specifying the `long` to use as the foreign key column.

View this answer as a nudge on a different track. Research this topic more to see if it fits your use case.